# How to ignore exception in a loop and continue the excution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception

I have following for loop in Java

```
List<String> accountList=new ArrayList<>();
int colNo=3;
for(int rowNo=1;rowNo<=tableRowNumber;rowNo++)
    {
            String accountName=getTableData(By.xPath(".//*[@id='accTable']/"), rowNo, colNo);
            accountList.add(accountName);
    }
```

The method getTableData(By,rowNo,colNo) is used to retrieve data in the table. When I run the code, if no data is specific cell the method throws

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

exception. It is ok, but the execution of the loop stops on exception. How can I ignore the exception so that the loop continues even if the exception occurs

Comment: How do you handle any other exceptions?

Comment: put try catch inside the loop

Comment: If you ignore exceptions like that then you're creating a non-deterministic test.

Comment: Then how can I get solution for the above problem? - @AndrewRegan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `try/catch` block, without anything in the `catch`

```
for (....) {
    try {
        String accountName=getTableData(By.xPath(".//*[@id='accTable']/"), rowNo, colNo);
        accountList.add(accountName);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```